# How to edit a Datatable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I'm having an issue with the functionality of editing my datatable.  I have the ability to add new rows and delete rows, but when it comes to editing I'm finding myself a bit lost.

I've looked at a ton of different ways but none of them seem to be what I'm wanting to do.

On each row, there's a delete icon and a edit icon.  Upon clicking the edit icon, a modal appears where the user can input the data for the rows (this is also how the add new row is done).

Here's some code:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> Job</th>
            <th> Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here's the function editRow() that I have right now:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable();
let id = document.getElementById('id').value;
let job = document.getElementById('job').value;
let title = document.getElementById('title').value;
table.row.replace(['<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="editTableData"><i class="mdi mdi-pencil" title="Edit"></i></button><button class="btn"><i class="mdi mdi-delete" title="Delete"></i></button>',
id,
job,
title
]);
```

Unfortunately, table.row.replace() doesn't work, it was just the last thing I had tried so that's why that's there.

So I click the edit icon - it brings up a modal, I have the functionality of the modal working by storing the value.  Just not sure how to identify the elements in the row to change.  For example:

I have a row:

```
               ID         JOB      Title
*edit icon*    1          SW       Manager
*edit icon*    2          SW       Engineer
```

so I click the *edit icon*

It brings up a modal, how can I take the data from the modal and replace it with the current data in the row.  I think identifying the row itself is giving me trouble as well.

Sorry if this is a bit hard to understand, please let me know if you need more information or if you need me to explain something better.  Also, if you want the modal code just let me know - I didn't add it because I didn't think it would be necessary.

Thank you!

Comment: What does an example row look like? It seems you'd need some sort of selector for the row elements. `<div id="row-1"><div id="id">1</div><div id="job">SW</div>....` so that you can select the rows?  `$('#table > #row-1 > #id')`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that I may need a selector for it.  I was just a bit confused on adding an ID everytime I create a row, and then let's say row 2 gets deleted, how to make row 3 become row 2 etc.  Maybe I'm overthinking that?

Comment: the elements should be returned in the order they appear in the DOM, so probably wouldn't need to actually keep track of the row id, and could probably just do `$('tr`)[1]` or something similar, like `$("tr > #job")[1]`

Comment: @Hobbitbob If you post dataTable contructor I can help you. How you load data in datatable?